# MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR when using MQ 7.5 with ASP.Net 4.8

Tags: asp.net, .net, ibm-mq

I have an ASP.Net 4.8 application which is connecting to MQ using SSL. The non-SSL part works fine i.e. I am able to connect to MQ if I use non SSL connection so the problem is in SSL.

MQ team has setup SSL at their end and I MQ 7.5 client is installed on my machine. I am using `amqmdnet.dll` in my application. MQ team provided me with following:

1. SSL certificate: I have imported it in Windows machine
2. Root certificate: I have also imported it in Windows machine
3. jks file: I have converted this file to `.kdb` file using utility `runmqckm`

Here is my code and the error message I am getting:

```
queueProperties[MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = "mq.ssl.local";
queueProperties[MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = 443;
queueProperties[MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = "Some Channel";
queueProperties[MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY] = "some user";
queueProperties[MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY] = "some password";
queueProperties[MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY] = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
queueProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, @"C:\Keystore.kdb");
queueProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
```

When using `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT` as shown above, I get error `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE`

If I use `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED` then I get error `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN`.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue? MQ is very confusing.

**EDIT**

When I use the following, then I get error `MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR`

```
MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
queueProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
```

Comment: Went are you using 7.5?  It has been out of support for over five years.

Comment: The `MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY` should reference the stub of the kdb in unmanaged mode,  ex `C:\Keystore` (leave off the kdb).